# How can I put pictures in selectize with angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to show in my selectize options a picture of each item.

This is an example of selectize and angular - how can I show pictures in selectize?

```
$scope.myModel = 1;

$scope.myOptions = [
  {id: 1, title: 'Spectrometer', img:'1.jpg'},
  {id: 2, title: 'Star Chart', img:'2.jpg'},
  {id: 3, title: 'Laser Pointer', img:'2.jpg'}
];

$scope.myConfig = {
  create: true,
  valueField: 'id',
  labelField: 'title',
  delimiter: '|',
  placeholder: 'Pick something',
  onInitialize: function(selectize){
    // receives the selectize object as an argument
  },
  // maxItems: 1
};
<selectize config='myConfig' options='myOptions' ng-model="myModel"></selectize>
```

If I have this, how can pass the image?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the [custom rendering functions](https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/usage.md#rendering). Each function should accept two arguments: "data" and "escape" and return HTML (string) with a single root element. The "escape" argument is a function that takes a string and escapes all special HTML characters.

In your example you can use them like this:

```
$scope.myModel = 1;

$scope.myOptions = [
  {id: 1, title: 'Spectrometer', img:'1.jpg'},
  {id: 2, title: 'Star Chart', img:'2.jpg'},
  {id: 3, title: 'Laser Pointer', img:'2.jpg'}
];

$scope.myConfig = {
  create: true,
  valueField: 'id',
  labelField: 'title',
  delimiter: '|',
  placeholder: 'Pick something',
  onInitialize: function(selectize){
    // receives the selectize object as an argument
  },
  // maxItems: 1

  //custom rendering functions for option & item :
    render: {
      option: function(item, escape) {
        return '<div class="option">' +
          '<img src="'+item.img+'" alt="'+scape(item.title)+'" height="42" width="42">' +
          '<span>'+scape(item.title)+'</span>' +
          '</div>';
      },
      item: function(item, escape) {

        return '<div class="item">'+
        '<img src="'+item.img+'" alt="'+scape(item.title)+'" height="42" width="42">'+
        '+scape(item.title)+' + 
        '</div>';
      }
    }
};

<selectize config='myConfig' options='myOptions' ng-model="myModel"></selectize>
```